# How can i hit the rss feed url in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to hit this url using jquery

```
http://localhost:8161/admin/queueBrowse/sourcename?view=rss&feedType=rss_2.0
```

How can i do this by passing the parameters as view=rss&feedType=rss_2.0

Comment: What do you mean, you "want to hit" it? Do you want to forward to that page, load that page in the exiting file, call that page via AJAX?

Comment: I want to hit that url and read the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

To load that XML file via AJAX for processing with jQuery, you can use the following code:

```
$.get("http://localhost:8161/admin/queueBrowse/sourcename", {
        view: 'rss',
        feedType: 'rss_2.0'
    }, function (xml) {
        // process xml here

    }, "xml");
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Thanks for giving the reply.If i do like this i am not able to hit the URL.What might be the Pbm.I am not even getting any error.If i see the browser using firebug the url is in red colour.

Comment: That's an error, usually means the url is not valid. I assume if you access that url directly in your browser it shows you xml?

Comment: It will not show the xml file but it will show the feed messages.I tried it by placing the direct url into the browser.I am new to this jquery.If any mistakes plz excuse me.

Comment: If i open the same url directly in chrome it will show the xml file.

Comment: Ok, is the JavaScript on the same server? Or is it accessing the file from a different domain?

Comment: When you get the red URL in Firebug, click on the URL and then click on the XML tab, what does it show in there?

Comment: It is showing as  XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{ab6f4de2-75c0-43dd-bcb9-23051334057b} Line Number 1, Column 1:

Comment: And if you click the Header tab, what does it say under Referer?

Comment: Under Header tab i am getting Content-Type text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1
Server Jetty(7.1.6.v20100715)
Set-Cookie JSESSIONID=5k2ps2w6rzrh1rsxxxv7arrjk;Path=/admin
Transfer-Encoding chunked

Comment: One more thing if i open my application in chrome then in firebug it is showing the error as XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8161/admin/queueBrowse/source?view=rss&feedType=rss_2.0. Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: I think this might be a cross domain issue. Try downloading [jquery.xdomainajax.js](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js). Include this script right after your jquery `<script>` tag and try again.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion but no use.It is giving same error.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this..

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "//localhost:8161/admin/queueBrowse/sourcename",
        data:{
              view: 'rss',
              feedType: 'rss_2.0'
             }
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });

function xmlParser(xml){
//process XML
}
```